# accessing jar-files from tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jar, classpath

he there,

been stuck for a while now. What im trying to do comes down to this:

- I have developed a little library which i am deploying in form of a jar-file. it contains a file i need to access, which is located in "json2/json.js" (yep, doin jscript/rhino things)
- I import the jar-file into a classical java-project, it works fine. File is found and read
- I import the SAME jar-file into tomcat-project which looks as follows:
- a .jsp that calls a java-class
- inside the java-class i call my library, which is located in the tomcat/lib-directory
- now when i try to access the file i cant (null-pointer)

sources:

```
        InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("json2/json.js");
```

when i run it inside the tomcat, (in==null).

for diagnosis i improvised the following:

```
        File fu = new File(new URI(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").toString()));
        String[] l = fu.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i+"||"+l[i]);
        }
```

with the classic java-class it only produces my main-class-file. in tomcat it shows me the content of the "tomcat/lib"-directory.

any ideas? would be greatly appreciated...

---

EDIT

one detail that i forgot to add (and that really grinds my gears):

```
SParser.class.getClassLoader().getParent().getResource("")
```

comes up with a null-ptr. wtf? im not accessing a particular ressource, still no result.

Comment: Where do you put your jar in tomcat? In WEB-INF/lib of your app?

Comment: So json2/json.js is inside a jar file in your tomcat/lib folder ?

Comment: the jar-file is in the tomcat/lib-directory, and inside it is the file (json2/json.js).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use `getSystemResourceAsStream()`. Use `getResourceAsStream()`. On a Tomcat webapp environment, the system classloader has no knowledge of `Tomcat/lib` nor the webapp libraries.

Also, when grabbing the `ClassLoader`, you should preferably grab the context class loader of the current thread.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/json/json.js");
```

Comment: thanks for help. i like your reasoning and have changed all my calls, still the problems persists...

Comment: I updated the answer. You have probably had the wrong classloader.

Comment: that did the trick... thank you about a million times! have a beer and feel awesome about yourself. YAY!

Comment: You're welcome. Just set your beer missile target to 12.12075,-68.85825.

Answer (score 0):

Put the JAR file in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your application.

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately it didnt work. same problem. tomcats finds the .jar-file, since both source-sample above are already inside the jar-file. so it only cant locate the ressources from the same archive!?!??!