# how to read files which located inside a jar from a class inside another jar in a web application

Tags: java, properties, jar

Here is my problem:

I write a util class Config.java:

```
public static Properties getProperties(String filename, Class clazz) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream ins = null;
    try {
        if (clazz == null) {
            ins = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(filename);
        } else {
            ins = clazz.getResourceAsStream(filename);
        }
        logger.info("load properties with filename: " + filename);
        if (ins != null) {
            prop.load(ins);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Error while loading file: " + filename, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ins != null) {
                ins.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error while close inputstream: " + filename, ex);
        }
    }
    return prop;
}
```

and I compile this code into a jar whose name is: gs-common.jar.

I also write a class named AnalysisDBService and invoke Config class as follows:

```
Properties properties = Config.getProperties("longKeywordRule.properties",AnalysisDBService.class);
```

and compile this biz project into jar:gs-biz.jar.

and I write a web applciation which dependends on gs-common and gs-biz(actually gs-common.jar and gs-biz.jar is located in /WEB-INF/lib). 
but I just found the properties file in gs-biz.jar cannot be loaded when the web application start up in tomcat.

could somebody tell me how to do this?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5487318/181336?

Comment: yeah, I read it, but I do have a another new request, I need to load the property file inside gs-biz.jar automatically when get the web application start up. and even I don't know what is the property file name or how many property files does exist inside the gs-biz.jar